# How to draw a marker with dashed/dotted edge in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a marker (a star) with dashed border lines instead of a solid border. Is there a way to do this in matplotlib? Here is a simple code that draws a marker with a solid border:

```
plot([1],[1],marker=(5,1,0),markersize=30,mfc='gold',mec='k',mew=1)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I use `scatter` to do that

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6,4)
plt.scatter(0.5, 0, marker='*', s=1000, facecolors='y', edgecolors='b')
plt.scatter(1.5, 0, marker='*',s=1000, facecolors='y', edgecolors='b',linestyle='--')
plt.xlim(0,2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Attention!** For some reason this response was down voted, while the example still works (at least for `Python 2.7.15rc1` and `Python 3.6.9`, when I'll have access to newer versions I will test it with them).

**But! The plot must be saved it as `*.eps`, saving as `*.png` does not work -- I don't know why. Maybe something with rendering..? I verified the `*.eps` file opening it in `gimp` and there are no lines inside the opened squares, so the file seems to correct.**

Well, I had the exactly opposite problem, i.e., I wanted to plot markers using solid lines (not dashed, dotted, etc...).
If you pass a `linestyle` to `plot` it should (unfortunately for me) plot the marker edge in the style of the passed `linestyle`.
Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
y = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25];
plt.plot(x, y, 
         label='y = x^2',
         linestyle=':',
         marker='s',
         color='r',
         mec='r',
         markersize=10,
         mfc=(1,1,1,0.0)
);
plt.legend(loc='best', ncol=1, fontsize=13);
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.eps', format='eps', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight');
```

Yeah, I know, no semicolons in python. :)
This is funny, but the markers are not visible after `plt.show()` -- saving the whole plot is required.
If you want to get the solid marker back just change last value in `mfc` (alpha channel I suppose) to, e.g., `0.0001`. This allows keeping the markers solid but still 'almost' transparent.

Comment: using `linestyle` in this way doesn't change the marker style for me.

Comment: @abcd `linestyle` changes the style of the line (as the name suggests ;)). To change the marker use the `marker` option, e.g., `marker=d` or sth similar.

Answer (score -1):

A 'DIY' method.

1. Plot a star.
2. Plot some circle without with white markeredgecolor. It will cover the star border. So the star looks like dashed line.
3. Fill in the star with gold color, but without border.

The code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot([1], [1], marker=(5, 1, 0), markersize=30, mfc='none', mec='k', mew=1)

for i in range(4):
    plt.plot([1], [1], marker='o', markersize=30-5*i,
             mfc='none', mec='w', mew=1)

plt.plot([1], [1], marker=(5, 1, 0), markersize=30, mfc='gold', mec='k', mew=0)
plt.show()
```

The result figure is this:

[image: result figure]

A little weird. But it works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i downvoted this just because the answer isn't general.